# How to check if Adobe Acrobat Reader is installed

Tags: installation, inno-setup, acrobat, foxit

I have this code that prompts the user to install Foxit PDF reader. How can I check whether the computer has Adobe Acrobat Reader is installed or not?

```
[Components]
Name: "foxit"; Description: "Foxit"; Types: "games"; ExtraDiskSpaceRequired: "30000000"; Check: "not AcrobatExists";
```

If Adobe Acrobat Reader is not found, then I want to start the install for Foxit Reader.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This question is like a _write this code for me_ request, and SO is not a site for that. You have to show your effort and ask specific questions if you have some while doing your job.

Comment: Here's a start: `function AcrobatExists: Boolean;`. There are examples of functions in the examples, and the online documentation has information about checking for things being installed (although not Foxit specifically) that you can use to get you started. (There's a link to the online docs in the help file.) Once you've done that, you can edit your question to be more specific and post what you've done so far to try and solve it. Good luck. :-)

Comment: I suggest that a better alternate question would be how to detect whether there was already ANY .pdf reader installed (not just Acrobat), by checking file associations.  There are more than just that one, which you should know as you're planning to install one of the alternatives yourself anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Acrobat Reader - Detect installed version](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Acrobat_Reader_-_Detect_installed_version) script:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Acrobat
AppVerName=Acrobat
DefaultDirName={pf}\Acrobat
DisableStartupPrompt=true
Uninstallable=false
DisableDirPage=true
OutputBaseFilename=Acrobat
CreateAppDir=false


[Code]

function GetAcrobatReaderVersion(): String;
var
  sVersion:  String;
begin
  sVersion := '';
  RegQueryStringValue( HKLM, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\AcroRd32.exe',
     '', sVersion );
  GetVersionNumbersString( sVersion , sVersion );
  Result := sVersion;
end;


function NextButtonClick(CurPage: Integer): Boolean;
begin

  // by default go to next page
  Result := true;

  if CurPage = wpWelcome then
  begin

    if Length( GetAcrobatReaderVersion() ) = 0 then
    begin
      MsgBox( 'There is not installed Acrobat reader',  mbInformation, MB_OK );
      Result := false;
    end
    else
      MsgBox( 'Acrobat reader installed is version ' + GetAcrobatReaderVersion() ,
           mbInformation, MB_OK );

  end;

end;
```

You can take GetAcrobatReaderVersion() and make a check function, for example:

```
function AcrobatExists(): Boolean;
begin
    result := Length( GetAcrobatReaderVersion() ) <> 0;
end;
```

Comment: It might be better to make a `Check` function (even OP asked for it). But except this will be better to follow Miral's note, that it's better to check if the *.pdf file extension has registered application in Shell rather than just check for Acrobat Reader (even if OP has the `Check` function name like that).

Comment: To your update, wouldn't be enough to have `Result := RegQueryStringValue(...);` in the check function (just check if the registry key value exists) ?